# Enabling zooming in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, zooming

So I'm trying to enable zooming in UITableView so you make the cells bigger. I know UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. So I went to the interface builder and changed minimum zoom to .75, max to 4.0, paging enabled, bounce scroll enabled. However, it is not zooming. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

UITableView does not zoom for some unknown reason even though it is a sub class of UIScrollView.
If you want to zoom UITableView follow the following steps..

1. take a UIScrollView(s), UIView(v), UITableView(t).
2. set delegate for UITableView(t), UIScrollView(s) to file owner and set dataSource for UITableView(t) to file owner.
3. make UITableView(t) as sub view of UIView(v).
4. make UIView(v) as sub view of UIScrollview(s).
5. now add UIScrollView(s) as sub view of your file owner's view or anything else.
6. put -(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView function in your *.m file. and return UIView(v).
7. now apply pinch gesture on UITableView(t), table will zoom.

Answer (score 1):

In most applications of `UITableView` I have seen, the zoom capability of the `UIScrollView` superclass is not active.  That is, zoooming is not used to change the size of a cell, nor to alter the amount of information visible on a single page of the table.  The scrolling capability is intended merely to browse through the contents of the table's cells.  Put another way, not all of the capabilities of the superclass are used in the subclass in this case.

If your intent is to make the cell larger to accommodate more information, then there is good information in the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1).  If you had other ideas about what zooming would accomplish on a table, maybe you could elaborate?

Comment: Well on one ipad app, pageonce finance, the UITable offers zooming capabilities. The main reason I wanted this is because we don't know what font size we should use for the cell text. We want to make it readable, but not exclude elderly people who have been complaining about the already large font size. Thanks for the info, though. Yeah, I had not seen any zooming on tables before that app, and I tried googling it but was not very helpful.

Comment: In this case it sounds like you'd instead want to use a pinch gesture.